# How to get request.user.username in django logger?

Tags: python-3.x, django, logging, django-models, django-views

I am trying to get the login username in Django logger but no luck and not able to figure out where I am doing a mistake.
Please find my code:

**a)code in settings.py**

```
import logging
import logging.config

    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        # Version of logging
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    
    #########formatter#########################
            'formatters': {
              'verbose': {
                          'format': '%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s-- %(module)s - %(process)d - %(thread)d - %(message)s'
    },
             'simple': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] : %(levelname)5s : %(message)s: %(user)'
    },
              
        },
    #########################Handlers ##################################
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'level': 'INFO',
                'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
                'filename': 'abc.log',
                'formatter': 'simple'
            },
    
            'console': {
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "level": "DEBUG",
            },
        },
    
    #################### Loggers ###############(A single Logger can have multiple handler )
    
        'loggers': {
            'django': {
                'handlers': ['file','console'],
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'propagate': True,
                'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG')
            },
    
        },
    }
```

**b)code in views.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("django")
```

**c)function in view.py where I am trying to show username.**

```
def retrievects1_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        logger.info('CTADashboard Page is opened!',request.user.username)
        logger.debug('My message with %s', 'args', extra={'user': request.user.username})
        print(request.user.username)
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
          -----Continue----

**O/p in the log file:**
[2021-01-07 18:47:32,780] :  INFO : "GET /exportctatot_data/? HTTP/1.1" 200 9728:
[2021-01-07 18:47:45,202] :  INFO : "GET /gensall/ HTTP/1.1" 200 82259:
[2021-01-07 18:47:46,145] :  INFO : Home Page is opened!:  #**here username is not coming**
[2021-01-07 18:47:46,148] :  INFO : "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6480:
[2021-01-07 18:47:47,004] :  INFO : "GET /shift/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4333:
[2021-01-07 18:47:48,073] :  INFO : "GET /ctaall/ HTTP/1.1" 200 30386:
[2021-01-07 18:47:53,080] :  INFO : "GET /exportctatot_data/? HTTP/1.1" 200 9728:
```

I am checking above log after user login.Any help/suggestion on this would be very helpful.

Comment: try using `request.user.name` if you are using default Django User class

Comment: yes I have used logger.info('CTADashboard Page is opened!',request.user.username) as shown in my view but no luck.

Comment: read my comment again Sir

Comment: sorry @SLDem you talking to take it in settings.py 'simple' I have checked that also.

Comment: I think `logger.info('CTADashboard Page is opened!',request.user.username)`  is missing the %s inside the info message string.

Comment: @JohnGardounis Thanks for pointing but still I'm not able to correct it.
Can you Please help me where Exactly I have to use it?

Comment: @Shailesh in your view.py in the retrievects1_view function you say: `if request.user.is_authenticated: logger.info('CTADashboard Page is opened!',request.user.username)`  . Modify that last part to `logger.info('CTADashboard Page is opened %s !',request.user.username)`  and see what it does.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGardounis!!Now I am getting a username.
If you don't mind I have 1 more doubt if I am using   'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] : %(levelname)5s : %(message)s: %(user)' in logger and in views.py   logger.debug('My message with %s', 'args', extra={'user': request.user}) then Why I'm not getting username in same log line.

Comment: Not sure but I think  `extra={'user': request.user}` should be  `extra={'user': request.user.username}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226982/discussion-between-shailesh-and-john-gardounis).